# Return var in a Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want return the var "Page" in a Jquery function :

```
var Page ;

 $('#Montant').dblclick(function(){

     $("#Encadrement_Encaissement_Menu_Creation").show();

     return Page = 'Crea_Bouton';
 }); 

alert(Page); //does not work
```

But its does not work.

The goal is not to make an alert of the var Page.

In a other page i have : if(Page == 'Crea_Bouton') { //Action }

So, Page must be a global var

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive. `page !== Page`

Comment: @Stephen not to mention that returning a value from the click handler doesn't make sense...

Comment: I can't decide if this is some sort of [x-y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It looks to me like OP has no idea of what (s)he's even asking.

Comment: Variable naming notwithstanding, there's still the issue of delayed execution of the event such that no variable has been set when the `alert` is triggered.

Comment: Sory, you need more information.

The goal is not to make an alert of the var Page.

In a other page i have :
if(Page == 'Crea_Bouton') { //Action }

So, Page must be a global var.

Comment: @zzzzBov I think you have a point. Didn't know that's what it's called, but it would be a lot better if the question was clearer about the problem that is trying to be solved.  *why* do you want `Page` outside of the event handler itself?  What is it going to be used for?

Comment: @Flo see my updated answer.  Your alert isn't going to work immediately as you've written it, the alert MUST execute sometime after the double click occurs if you want the variable to have anything in it.

Comment: You mentioned "another page". If it is truly a separate HTML page then none of the javascript variables you set on the previous page will be accessible or even set at all because html is a stateless medium.  You have to use query params or a server-side language to transfer state between pages.  With that said, my answer will suffice if you need to check that `page` variable and you have not accessed a new HTML page yet.

Answer (score 4):

There's several issues here.  First of all, `Page` and `page` are two different variables, but let's assume you've named them the same - your code still won't work.

The problem is, your event handler is not run immediately, it's only run when the double click occurs.  Defining `page` outside of the event *doesn't make any sense* in this context.  What happens is it hits `var page;` first, then it registers an event (but DOES NOT run the event function), then alerts an empty variable (because the event has not been triggered yet).

When you do trigger the dblclick event, that alert doesn't get executed.

Try this:

```
var page;
$('#Montant').dblclick(function(){

  $("#Encadrement_Encaissement_Menu_Creation").show();

  page = 'Crea_Bouton';
});

$('#anotherdiv').click(function(){
  if(page === 'Crea_Bouton'){
    alert("yep!");
  }else{
    alert("Something else")
  }
})
```

Now, when your `#anotherdiv` is clicked, it will only alert 'yep!' if the original `Montant` div has been double clicked first.  Otherwise it'll do something else (or nothing at all if you omit the `else`).

Here's an example jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wb9Ba/

If you click the second button right away, it says "Something else", but if you double click the first button, and then click the second button, it says "yep!"

Answer (score 1):

Use a "callback" function as jQuery does:

```
function onReturn(page) {
   // Process your returned value
   if (page == 'Crea_Bouton') {
       // Action
       alert(page);
   }
}

$('#Montant').dblclick(function(){
   $("#Encadrement_Encaissement_Menu_Creation").show();
   var page = 'Crea_Bouton';
   onReturn(page);
});
```

Or process your value inside the dblclick callback:

```
$('#Montant').dblclick(function(){
   $("#Encadrement_Encaissement_Menu_Creation").show();
   var page = 'Crea_Bouton';

   // Do something with my page
   if (page == 'Crea_Bouton') {
       // Action
       alert(page);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the anonymous method inside `dblclick` is asynchronous, it's impossible to return something.

Instead, you may create a new function:

```
var page;

$('#Montant').dblclick(function () {
    $("#Encadrement_Encaissement_Menu_Creation").show();
    display('Crea_Bouton');
}); 

function display(page) {
    alert(page);
    // ...
}
```